# I could not been able to get my buttons "activated" so that I can change it's color as well as make a sound for it in this particular task?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

While i was trying to build this game it kept showing me this error saying:

> Syntax error and unrecognized expression

as if it's not recognizing the `$` sign which I also included the jQuery script source to my HTML document.

Please i need someone to look through my JS code and tell me why this error keeps showing

```js
function activateTile(color) {
  let tile = $('"' + '.' + color + '"')
  let sound = new Audio('"' + 'sounds' + '/' + color + '.mp3' + '"');
  tile.addClass("pressed")
  sound.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    tile.removeClass("pressed")
  }, 300);
}
function playRound(nextSequence) {
  nextSequence.forEach((color, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      activateTile(color);
    }, (index + 1) * 600);
  });
}
function nextStep() {
  const tiles = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
  const random = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  return random;
}
function nextRound() {
  level += 1;
  const nextSequence = [...sequence];
  nextSequence.push(nextStep());
  playRound(nextSequence);
}
function startGame() {
  $("h1").text("wait for the computer")
  nextRound();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
    <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
    <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you call those functions, specifically `startGame()`?

Comment: I called the startGame() function in my browser console as it supposed to revoke all other function afterwards !.